# Unit Test Project Accessor does not create all private methods

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011

I had a project that I had previously created a unit test for which required the autogenerated Accessor class.  Everything worked great.  But then I created a new class in the same project, that I needed to unit test.  When I looked at the Accessor class, the new method wasn't there (although some other proetected methods were).

I went to the class file and right clicked and selected Created Private Accessor, but was greeted by two error messageboxes, "Private accessor creation failed for 'Foo'.", and "A reference to the component 'Foo' already exists in the project."

A little more trouble shooting and I discovered that if any private method had a parameter that was one of my auto generated CRM entity types it wouldn't show up in the Accessor class.  (not sure if it was CRM related, or just the dll itself).  Why won't my methods show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally bit the bullet and shut down all of my VS instances I had running, and opened a new instance, recompiled, and they showed up just fine.  Wish I could have gotten that 2 hours of trouble shooting back...  :(